# Zend framework fatal error in skelton aplication

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework, error-handling

Fatal error: Class 'Album\Album' not found in /var/www/html/zf2/module/Album/Module.php on line 43

this error is showing whenever i am trying ti access localhost/album

my module.php

```
<?php
 namespace Album;
 use Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet;
 use Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway;
 use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\AutoloaderProviderInterface;
 use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\ConfigProviderInterface;
 use Album\Model\AlbumTable;
 class Module implements AutoloaderProviderInterface,ConfigProviderInterface{
 public function getAutoloaderConfig()
 {
     return array(
         'Zend\Loader\ClassMapAutoloader' => array(
             __DIR__ . '/autoload_classmap.php',
         ),
         'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
             'namespaces' => array(
                 __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
             ),
         ),
     );
 }

 public function getConfig()
 {
     return include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';
 }

     public function getServiceConfig()
 {
     return array(
         'factories' => array(
             'Album\Model\AlbumTable' =>  function($sm) {
                 $tableGateway = $sm->get('AlbumTableGateway');
                 $table = new AlbumTable($tableGateway);
                 return $table;
             },
             'AlbumTableGateway' => function ($sm) {
                 $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                 $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
            $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new Album());
                 return new TableGateway('album', $dbAdapter, null, $resultSetPrototype);
             },
         ),
     );
 }}?>
```

how to solve this error?
please give me the solution,zend is looking so tough i m trying to learn zend from 2 weeks bt this error is just eating my mind.
please help guyz

Comment: Does the Album class exist? In which file is it defined?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your namespaces are set up correctly. Your Album class has to be in the Album namespace if you're calling it like you are. Otherwise use the fully qualified name.

Comment: Error still persisit,error is giving in line 43
 $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new Album());

Comment: where is your Album class located? Is it in Album\Album ? It's most likely a namespace issue...